# Grouping by multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of ParentID's which are products made by combining the required amount of the corresponding BaseID product.

Product table:

```
    ParentID    BaseID    Required    UOH
    -------------------------------------
    1           55        1           400
    1           56        .5          400
    2           55        1           400
    2           57        1           400
    3           58        1           0
```

I need to  select the ParentID's where there are enough of each required base product (UOH) to create the Parent.

The Query should return

```
    ParentID
    ----------------
    1
    2
```

The only way I know how to do this is by using a pivot view. Is there another or a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ParentID FROM [product table] WHERE UOH > 0

Comment: Using that query, if BaseID 57 has a UOH of 0, ParentID 2 is still returned even though it can'd be produced. That's why I think some sort of grouping on ParentID is necessary

Answer (score 4):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select parentid
from table t
group by parentid
having sum(case when uoh < required then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

The `having` clause counts the number of times where `uoh` is less than required.  If the count is zero, then all base ids have sufficient amounts.